# Convert XML to array

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I am trying to create currency converter in CakePHP app and I have API generated XML from my bank but don't have idea how to convert it in array so I can use later on for conversion.

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kursnalista datum="23.01.2014">
    <valuta oznaka="eur" kup="115.3335" sre="115.6805" pro="116.0275" />
    <valuta oznaka="usd" kup="85.1484" sre="85.4046" pro="85.6608" />
    <valuta oznaka="chf" kup="93.3572" sre="93.6381" pro="93.919" />
    <valuta oznaka="gbp" kup="140.9944" sre="141.4187" pro="141.843" />
    <valuta oznaka="aud" kup="74.9552" sre="75.1807" pro="75.4062" />
    <valuta oznaka="cad" kup="76.4709" sre="76.701" pro="76.9311" />
    <valuta oznaka="sek" kup="13.1298" sre="13.1693" pro="13.2088" />
    <valuta oznaka="dkk" kup="15.4518" sre="15.4983" pro="15.5448" />
    <valuta oznaka="nok" kup="13.8004" sre="13.8419" pro="13.8834" />
    <valuta oznaka="jpy" kup="0.815712" sre="0.818166" pro="0.82062" />
    <valuta oznaka="hrk" kup="" sre="15.1381" pro="" />
    <valuta oznaka="kwd" kup="" sre="301.7227" pro="" />
    <valuta oznaka="pln" kup="" sre="27.7751" pro="" />
    <valuta oznaka="czk" kup="" sre="4.202" pro="" />
    <valuta oznaka="huf" kup="" sre="0.382049" pro="" />
    <valuta oznaka="bam" kup="" sre="59.1465" pro="" />
</kursnalista>
```

So, how can I convert this to use in PHP for conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp has a core utility for handling XML. You can check out the documentation at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html. I use it all the time and it works great.